# Array parsing and converting to new array List with specific output

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to convert below array to flat one line array using TypesCript/JavaScript?

```
Student: any = [
  { "id": "1", "name": "Jhon", "Marks": { "Math": "90", "English": "80", "Science": "70" } },
  { "id": "2", "name": "Peter", "Marks": { "Math": "95", "English": "85", "Science": "75" } }
];
```

output should be like this:

```
NewStudent = [
  { "id": "1", "name": "Jhon", "Math": "90", "English": "80", "Science": "70" },
  { "id": "2", "name": "Peter", "Math": "95", "English": "85", "Science": "75" }
];
```

Comment: Hi! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Hi! When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful info in it. There was also a toolbar full of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area showing what your post would look like when posted, between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, so you'd look at it). Making your post clear, and showing that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: I've fixed the formatting for you.

Comment: thank you @T.J.Crowder for formatting..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let students = [
   { "id": "1", "name": "Jhon", "Marks": { "Math": "90", "English": "80", "Science": "70" } },
   { "id": "2", "name": "Peter", "Marks": { "Math": "95", "English": "85", "Science": "75" } }
];

let NewStudents = [];

students.map( item => {
   Object.assign( item, item.Marks);
   delete item["Marks"];
   NewStudents.push(item);
   return
});
```

NewStudents array would give your desired result.

Answer (score -1):

```
const students = [
    { "id": "1", "name": "Jhon", "Marks": { "Math": "90", "English": "80", "Science": "70" } },
    { "id": "2", "name": "Peter", "Marks": { "Math": "95", "English": "85", "Science": "75" } }
];
const newStudent = students.map(student => {id: student.id, name: student.name, ...student.marks})
```